# How do I reduce Simulink/Matlab model coverage run time?

Tags: matlab, unit-testing, code-coverage, simulink

I have a multiple top simulink model with reference models(Test requirement, A FMU Plant, A Controller & a Test Monitor ) running inside a Matlab parametrize unit test class. The simulink side is similar to Simulink Test, but it's a legacy model made in-house . I'm doing code coverage using cvtest,cvsim,cvhtml. It's part of a CI/CD pipeline on azure on a self-hosted windows computer. Currently the azure jobs takes 4h30. 23 min in a build task. 4h05 in test and coverage task with model coverage taking most of that time.  I've found out that most of the time is spent running the cvsim command. I only really need selective coverage of 1 of my reference models( 'Test Monitor') . Hence, I'm looking for way to get that number down. Any suggestion?

**ACTION:**

I have tried these test parameters with a cvtest object and pass it to cvsim:

fooSim.m - Snippet

```
testObj = cvtest(sys);
testObj.settings.decision = 1;
testObj.settings.designverifier = 1;
testObj.settings.mcdc = 1;
testObj.modelRefSettings.enable = 'filtered';
testObj.modelRefSettings.excludedModels = ["A","B","C","D" .."Z"];
testObj.sfcnSettings.enableSfcn = 0;
testObj.emlSettings.enableExternal = 0;
testObj.options.intervalStartTime = 0;
testObj.options.intervalStopTime = B;
paramStruct.StartTime = '0.0';
paramStruct.StopTime = string(duration);
paramStruct.ReturnWorkspaceOutputs = 'on'; 
[cvdo, simOutput] = cvsim(testObj,paramStruct) ;
cvhtml(cat(2,'SimCoverageReport',sys,'.html'), cvdo,'-hTR=1 -sRT=0');
cvexit;
bdclose('all');
```

Where A to Z are various reference model names and sub-reference model name without the .slx extension. Where B < Duration at the moment for debugging purposes.

TestFoo.m - Snippet

```
    methods (Test)
        function testfoo(testCase,File)
            duration = getDuration(File);
            [cvdo, simOutput] = fooSim(File,duration);
            passFailOut = saveResult(simOutput);
            testCase.verifyEqual(passFailOut ,true);
        end
        
    end
```

**EXPECTED & RESULT:**

I expected to have only 1 SimCoverage html Report and 1 Monitor html report per test. But I got 1 Sim coverage html report and a html report of all reference model and sub-reference models.(around 150 coverage files) X (my number of tests).

**INFO:**

Maybe I don't understand/not using it well the modelRefSettings.excludedModels documentation, but this line doesn't seem to affect my run time. Any additional details on that is welcome.

https://www.mathworks.com/help/slcoverage/ref/cvtest.html

I have not tried using sim function with the coverage GUI parameters, does that provide more flexibility than cvsim?: is CovModelRefExcluded different than modelRefSettings.excludedModels?

https://www.mathworks.com/help/slcoverage/ug/specify-model-coverage-options.html
https://www.mathworks.com/help/slcoverage/ref/recordcoverage.html

I have tried running it with testObj.modelRefSettings.enable = 'off'; but it only gives mes a top level coverage without any details on the monitor. Basically only execution coverage. It's much faster thought.

I have tried and failed parallelization. Any suggestion on that is helpful too.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is your issue happening in CI/CD pipeline only? If you do code coverage locally, do you also have this issue?

Comment: @CeceDong-MSFT Yea, I should removed the Azure-DevOps Tags. No, the behavior is the same in both pipeline and when I run it locally. My question is more Matlab related. How to optimize the parameters I have to make it run quicker.

Comment: I have a same issue.